# Is providing class weight to neural network enough for imbalanced binary classification?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, class-imbalance

I have a highly imbalanced binary classification problem, probably 95:5 for two classes. I don't want to perform resampling as the data is already huge and training it would just take more time. (I'm also aware of down sampling)

But my question is , is providing class weights (let's say computed by scikit-learn's [compute class weight](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html)) enough?
or there is any other method ?

```py
model.fit(X,y,class_weight=class_weight)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to an [answer to a similar question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/76385/why-to-adjust-class-weights-instead-of-simply-finding-the-best-threshold/76386#76386), you don't have any reason to handle unbalance from the beginning. An imbalance of 95:5 isn't that big, I'd start with the regular training and if that doesn't work try more sophisticated things.

Comment: Interesting, so does that mean models can learn the imbalance nature by themselves? and also can you link to a good read for the *sophisticated things*?

Comment: To me the sophisticated things are mainly downsampling and class weights (not very sophisticated right? they are at least less simple than plain training). I think there's a lot of confusion with imbalance in introductory DS blogs. Unless you're imbalance is very extreme ( < 1%) I don't think there's any reason to do any special thing as long as you are using cross-entropy loss. Not in my experience, not in any Kaggle competition I've seen